Is a religion that rejects the god plausible?
In the world that I'm inventing, there is a religion that originated from the cult of guardian spirits and the cult of ancestors. This religion treats the divine as something far removed from the human essence. So far away that it is pointless to pray to them, but they believe in guardian spirits and ancestral spirits who protect them and who are worth honoring.
In the mythology from which this religion grew, there is a spiritual hierarchy in the celestial and Chthonic world.
At the very top of the hierarchy, the higher gods (the father and mother of the entire pantheon), then the younger gods (sons and daughters), then the intermediary spirits (servants of the gods and their creations): aisars (this is their name). They are followed by guardian spirits of people (there is also a belief that everything has guardians, even the state): their name is larems.
I also see this religion as somewhat dualistic–Gods as the embodiment of nature, chaos and larems as the embodiment of civilization, humanity and reason. And aisars as the embodiment of spiritual passions.
The whole religion revolves around the story of the first larem, who took fire and gave it to people (the motive of stealing fire is quite common to many people). In response to the uprising, the god of fire and volcanoes punished him. But despite his eternal torment, his holy spirit gave birth to many spirits — the rest of the larems.
Generally can such a religion or religious philosophy plausible?
Specifically, this religious teaching has appeared in the conditions of urbanization and industrialization, when many residents from rural areas migrate to cities, would the residents have to create new religions in isolation from old religious traditions.

In your world you get to decide what is and isn’t possible. We’re not here to tell you what you should or shouldn’t build in your world. If you have a specific worldbuilding problem you want help with try asking about that instead.

VTC - There does not seem to be a World building question - can such a Religion exist - sure, if you say it does.

Sounds like a fun thing to construct. Thought provoking as to how you'd flesh it out - but I'm afraid it's too broad at present, can you narrow it to a specific question?

Possible and Plausible are two different questions.  As a matter of it being possible, of course it is.  But I think what the OP means to ask is if it is plausible, in which case this question becomes a matter of whether or not there is any historical and/or sociological justification for such a religion.

I took a crack at editing your wall-of-text post for readability and compliance with the rules. I failed. I'm forced to agree with @TheDemonLord that there isn't a worldbuilding question here - notably because the question asked in the title and any form of the questions asked in the body are not at all the same (you're allowed to ask one and only one question). It's worth noting that asking, "can X exist?" is pretty meaningless on this Stack. It's your imaginary world, so of course it can. Our sweet spot is helping you design the religion. But you seem to have already done that.

On a side note, @TheDemonLord, the idea of a religion that expressly rejects the gods is interesting... a religion that believes the gods exist, but are (perhaps) humanist nonetheless. What do you think the (very simple) catechism of such a religion would be?

"Their blood runs through my veins, Let the spirit of my father and his fill me with their strength and honor in the trials ahead, let my mother's line guide me with wisdom and compassion...."

@JBH - I mean - Such a religion could be along the lines of JBPs answer of 'I act as if God is real' - namely, you dont hold with all the supernatural and magical elements of a deity, but you keep the elements of judgement and morality etc. However Unless OP clarifies this is what they want, I dont see a World Building question. But perhaps if the OP wants to refine the question - there could be a really fun question here.

I don't think that there are any Gods in Jainism and probably not in Buddhism either.

@Slarty I really wish the OP would join us and clarify things. You're pointing out that it's possible to have a religion without gods (and I can point to the Religion of Science as a great example), but it seems the OP is asking for help with a religion that knows the gods exist, but rejects them... or possibly a religion that focuses on only one aspect of the pantheon and ignores the rest (which only matters if the gods are real...). It's confusing at this point.

I'd love to reopen this question --- but it has serious problems!  You are asking several different questions, and Stack Exchange only allows you to ask one focused question at a time. Then, your title question seems to be at odds with the question(s) in your post body. I would suggest you take this to our Sandbox for some help with how to write a good question!

Thank you for the answers, I wanted to know if this is realistic? I just wanted to write a book with a world built as realistically as possible. And I was thinking about a religion that rejects the gods. There are many currents in this religion that can be divided into two types:those who consider the gods to be simply beings far from humans, who are morally neither good nor evil. And those who consider the gods to be absolute evil, and the Larems to be absolute good.

This religion has a set of morals, and there is a theme of punishment/reward after death. The main goal of the followers of the doctrine is to become a larem after death, you can only become one by knowing love and kindness. The follower He must love everyone equally with absolute love, he must also be kind-minded, pious, and virtuous, and then he can gain immortality and become a larem.

Those who behaved unworthily end up in Avadur, a kind of spiritual hell where the wicked suffer, according to one version-from the gods they worshipped, on the other version-from monsters-the offspring of their vices

@TytoAlba - I think you miss the point of our critiques. There are 3 people (including myself) who are very experienced on WB:SE and love to give Answers - we are all in agreement - that with some tweaking - this could be a great question. Asking is it realistic - it could be if you say it is. It sounds like you are struggling with internal consistency - but if that is the case - you need to refine the question.

I'm pretty sure almost any linguist would find out which word meant "the sort of supernatural being one worships" and translate "larem" as "god". Then probably use the local words or adjective-noun combinations in English for other supernatural beings.

I would not say that larem is a deity, I created their image under the inspiration of Greco-Roman geniuses and daemons. Also, the image of the Aisars is very similar to the images of the Lasae spirits from Etruscan mythology. The difference between these spirits and the gods is that Larems and aisars are vulnerable creations of gods and they can be destroyed, while the gods according to their nature are invulnerable.

And larem is not worshipped, he is called for help, he is revered, but he is revered more as an elder of family than as a deity.

From a purely secular viewpoint, religions provide a society with a worldview and with rules which may or may not benefit the society in a given environment. Simultaneously, society pressures religion to conform to the rules of society. This leads to scripture like "thou shalt have no other gods" (promoting unity of the faith) or "render unto Caesar ..." (avoiding conflict with the government).
On a more detailed level, consider Jewish and Islamic dietary laws in the context of a middle eastern civilization without refrigerators, or the Protestant work ethic in the context of a developing capitalist society.
So the twin questions are:

Was the original belief system consistent with a successful society? I think so. Fill out details how even in the absence of a judging god, good deeds are rewarded and bad deeds are punished to encourage good deeds in society. The guardian spirits may help.
Were changes made necessary by urbanization? Depends on the details ...


This religion has a set of morals, and there is a theme of punishment/reward after death. The main goal of the followers of the doctrine is to become a larem after death, you can only become one by knowing love and kindness. The follower he must love everyone equally with absolute love, he must also be kind-minded, pious, and virtuous, and then he can gain immortality and become a larem.

Those who behaved unworthily end up in Avadur, a kind of spiritual hell where the wicked suffer, according to one version, from the gods they worshipped, on the other from monsters-the offspring of their vices.

@TytoAlba, so imagine a situation where all people used to live in small villages and had to "love" everybody in the village in the sense of "it takes a village to raise a child." A caring, nurturing environment. Then large cities develop, with thousands and tens of thousands of people. This level of care simply does not work any more. Does the religion still demand it, and all city dwellers have a guilty conscience, or is the religion redefined to set boundaries?

I would say that this religion arose to unite citizens who belong to different strata of society, crafts and different peoples: "Like, yes, we all have different deities and different languages with different names, but HEY, we all have guardian spirits and ancestral spirits, they protect and protect us

Jewish dietary laws have nothing to do with the absence of refrigerators.

Basic cleanliness is also a decent example of a behavior that religions often promote (for supernatural reasons), but which a scientist would recognize as having concrete, practical benefits for the survival of adherents.
